# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl Chapter 7.25

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi i'm a newbie working through Hartl. After a recent disaster I've been able to restore my app to a near working state (thanks Github!). I am now down to one error in my tests. So when I run the test I get:

```
sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/
..............................F

Failures:

1) User pages signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.61988 seconds
31 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48 # User pages signup with valid information after saving the user
```

Here's my user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit user_path(user) }

describe "signup" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
it "should not create a user" do
expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
end
end

describe "with valid information" do
before do
fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
end

it "should create a user" do
expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  describe "after saving the user" do
before { click_button submit }
it { should have_link('Sign out') }
end
end
end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your 'Sign out' link , probably something goes wrong there.

Comment: Can you explain this a little please i'm a newbie!

Comment: Hi as far as I can tell: 1) Probably the link is missing 2) The link's name is different than 'Sign out' 3) after the action of Click button 'submit', there is no 'Sign out' link. I am a newbie too :)

Comment: umm. It seems when you restore back to nearly working state, there is still code from chapter 8. I remember Sign out feature is discussed in Listing 8.26. You may check it out in chapter 8.

Comment: Yes I understand, however, this is code restored to Chapter 7 completion status. Why should it appear now? I need to get this test passed before continuing.

Comment: You probably commited some code from Chapter 8. Its definitely a test from Chapter 8. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out Check figure 8.6